# Creating an eBay fulfilment policy. ("Please select a valid postage service.")

Tags: postman, ebay-api

After a day of work with Postman, I have managed to reduce the number of errors down to 1. No idea how to get past it.

Definitely not an authorisation problem. I've been making lots of authorised calls.

## URI:

`POST https://api.ebay.com/sell/account/v1/fulfillment_policy`

## Body:

```
{
  "categoryTypes": [
    {
      "name": "ALL_EXCLUDING_MOTORS_VEHICLES"
    }
  ],
  "freightShipping": "false",
  "globalShipping": "false",
  "handlingTime": {
    "unit": "DAY",
    "value": "1"
  },
  "localPickup": "true",
  "marketplaceId": "EBAY_AU",
  "name": "100 grams",
  "shippingOptions": [
    {
      "costType": "CALCULATED",
      "optionType": "DOMESTIC",
      "shippingServices": [
        {
          "shippingCarrierCode": "Australia Post",
          "shippingServiceCode": "AU_Regular"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

## Output:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "errorId": 20403,
            "domain": "API_ACCOUNT",
            "category": "REQUEST",
            "message": "Invalid .",
            "longMessage": "Please select a valid postage service.",
            "inputRefIds": [
                "service"
            ],
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "XPATH",
                    "value": "DomesticItemShippingService[0].shippingService"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

## Things I've Tried:

- Deleting `"shippingOptions": [...]` (and everything inside the `[]`s) got rid of the errors and resulted in the successful creation of a new fulfillment policy. However, I wanted to include shipping options in my call.
- `shippingCarrierCode` doesn't seem to do anything. I've changed it to all sorts of sensible and non sensible things, including deleting it entirely. No impact on the output.
- Changing `shippingServiceCode` to anything non-standard (eg `"shippingServiceCode": "potato"`) results in getting the exact same error, but twice instead of once. (See below) How can I get the same error twice with only one shipping option?
- Including a domestic and international option, I get the same error twice also. (Same output as below, except the second `DomesticItemShippingService[1].shippingService` is instead `DomesticItemShippingService[0].shippingService`)
- Making an international option AND a domestic option, BOTH with silly service names results in 3 errors. (I was expecting 4.)

Code:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "errorId": 20403,
            "domain": "API_ACCOUNT",
            "category": "REQUEST",
            "message": "Invalid .",
            "longMessage": "Please select a valid postage service.",
            "inputRefIds": [
                "service"
            ],
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "XPATH",
                    "value": "DomesticItemShippingService[0].shippingService"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "errorId": 20403,
            "domain": "API_ACCOUNT",
            "category": "REQUEST",
            "message": "Invalid .",
            "longMessage": "Please select a valid postage service.",
            "inputRefIds": [
                "service"
            ],
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "XPATH",
                    "value": "DomesticItemShippingService[1].shippingService"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What did I do wrong this time?

Comment: There is differing documentation on that. I've tried both.

Comment: "Australia Post" "AustraliaPost" and "PotatoCucumber" all get the exact same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get an answer to my question. Not here, even though I sent them the link here, but I got the answer (eventually) through official eBay channels.

I'll post that answer here for everyone. I was thinking of adding correct stackoverflow formatting, but decided it would be better to leave the correct answer untouched from the original.

> Hello Jonathon ,
>
> Ignore my last message and Apologize for the confusion.
>
> Here is the reason why you are getting the error:
>
> You have to set  "localPickup": "false", refer doc for your help:
>   https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/account/resources/fulfillment_policy/methods/createFulfillmentPolicy#request.localPickup
>
> And you will get response as:
>
> {   "name": "100 grams",   "marketplaceId": "EBAY_AU",
>   "categoryTypes": [
>       {
>         "name": "ALL_EXCLUDING_MOTORS_VEHICLES",
>         "default": true
>       }   ],   "handlingTime": {
>       "value": 1,
>       "unit": "DAY"   },   "shippingOptions": [
>       {
>         "optionType": "DOMESTIC",
>         "costType": "CALCULATED",
>         "shippingServices": [
>           {
>             "sortOrder": 1,
>             "shippingCarrierCode": "Australia Post",
>             "shippingServiceCode": "AU_Regular",
>             "freeShipping": false,
>             "buyerResponsibleForShipping": false,
>             "buyerResponsibleForPickup": false
>           }
>         ],
>         "insuranceOffered": false,
>         "insuranceFee": {
>           "value": "0.0",
>           "currency": "AUD"
>         }
>       }   ],   "globalShipping": false,   "pickupDropOff": false,   "freightShipping": false,   "fulfillmentPolicyId": "6104871000",
>   "warnings": [] }
>
> Let us know if you need further assistance!!!
>
> Best Regards, eBay Developer Support

Answer (score 0):

Check them out [here](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/account/resources/fulfillment_policy/methods/createFulfillmentPolicy). Make sure you have all the required fields.

```
pickupDropOff
shippingOptions.shippingServices.shipToLocations.regionIncluded
```

Comment: fulfillmentPolicyId is an output, not an input. The other two are optional fields, not required fields.

That said, it was an honest attempt to answer the question, so you'll probably win the bounty.

Comment: Yeah sorry I must have misread it what about the headers [here](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/rest-request-components.html#HTTP)?

Comment: Those headers are relevant to authentication issues. I've managed to create a fulfillment policy without shipping options, so it's not an authentication issue. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to create any at all.

Comment: I'm becoming more and more convinced this is an issue on eBay's end. Likely Australia Post has been coded incorrectly.

Comment: Reach out to them!? I paid them USD$75 for them to ignore my question since March 19. (Another question I posted March 8, I ended up solving myself March 11. Luckily, I'm using the same USD$75 I paid for that one on this one.)

Comment: WOW that's not nice at all, have you actually tried filling out most or all the fields in `shippingServices`? If you cannot fix it until tomorrow I'll create an account and try it myself

Comment: Yeah, I tried it with lots of the optional fields filled in. Best of luck with creating the account. If you can navigate this minefield, eBay API can be your new career and new source of stackoverflow reputation.